# What's the train frequency at all stations in the UK?

Tags: data-request, uk, public-transport

I've been trying to find out how many trains stop at each UK train station, each day (or year, month, doesn't really matter but the more specific the better). But can't find any good sources.
Could also derive it from time-tables, but can't seem to find any good time tables in .csv or .xlsx...

Anyone can help me out?
Would be absolutely amazing!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can find the complete timetable in PDF [through Network Rail](http://www.networkrail.co.uk/aspx/3828.aspx).
You might be able to scrape the required information from it.

Otherwise, perhaps you can contact Network Rail directly to see if the information you're asking for is available.  In Sweden, [tydal.nu](http://www.tydal.nu/category/tag/) has had success in scraping information from a similar Swedish PDF timetable, so perhaps the people there have some code they are willing to share.

Comment: There are some related questions/answers with links to UK rail system data: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/498/are-there-any-open-mappings-of-train-station-identifiers-in-the-uk and http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4027/london-rail-and-tube-station-locations/4030#4030

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in calculating train frequency at London tube, overground and *some* national rail stations, you can use the Timetable API in the Transport for London Unified API. Timetables are returned in XML or JSON. For example:

https://tfl.gov.uk/tube/timetable/northern?fromId=940GZZLUCTN

You can find out more about the Transport for London Unified API by reading the [blog articles](http://blog.tfl.gov.uk/2015/10/19/unified-api-part-3-rot-routes-of-things/) I have written there.